# Export the top 5 rows of every table in a database to excel - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like a way to export the top 5 rows of every table within a database from SQL to an excel spreadsheet. The desired output would be an excel spreadsheet where each tab would be a different table from the database, containing the top 5 records (also a way of identifying what tab contains what table).

In the past I have done this for smaller databases (but I am trying to cut out the manual process, as I need to do this on several large databases), using the following methods:

```
USE Database_Name
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

I use this query to get a list of the table names within the database, then run the following code to get the top 5 rows of those tables in the same database:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 5 * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].
['+name+']'+';'
FROM sys.tables
EXEC(@sql)
```

The first and second query produce the tables in the same order. So previously I had copy and pasted the list of names into excel (from the first query), created a tab for each table name, then copy and pasted the top 5 rows (produced by the second query) into those tabs. I feel as if this could be done in a much better fashion/ be automated. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: How's your SSRS or powershell skills?

Comment: I am not familiar/ have never used those. In terms of SQL I have only used MS SQL Server.

Comment: In terms of automating they'd probably be your best bet, although you'll be facing a learning curve if you're not familiar with them. SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) is probably easier - you could drop in your query above more or less as-is, and use SSRS to format the output into named Excel tabs.

Comment: Now would this be a package/extension to MS SQL Server or a separate download. I assume it's a separate download, if so, does it connect just as easy to an AWS server? Also what is the benefit of using it, if the query syntax is very similar? Does it just have better exporting features or are you just more familiar with SSRS?

Comment: SSRS is part of the SQL Server product line (requires a SQL license), normally packaged with it; as of SQL 2017 for convenience it's a separate download/installer. It cannot be hosted on AWS, but an AWS server can be used as a datasource. All I'm exploiting here is its ability to generate dynamic, named sheets in an Excel workbook, it's in no way a replacement for SSMS (which I presume you're using).

Comment: As Gareth suggested, try using Powershell. You could use it to automate a loop of bCP commands to export each table to a csv

Comment: Rather than trying to get up to speed on Powershell/SSRS, is there a way to write all the tables to a csv individually? Then I could imagine writing a python script to compile all of the csvs or something along those lines.

Comment: I can write you an example to grab the data in powershell, could probably be converted to python, it's the knitting together into a single Excel file that I can't do.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I am jammed on some other work today but I will give it a shot within the next few days. Now does Powershell require an additional download (or a license) or can I run that within SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to get an individual csv file per table in powershell:
Might be rewriteable into Python  - it's just a call to `invoke-sqlcmd` (which in itself is a call to `sqlcmd.exe`) to get the list of tables, then a loop to export first 5 rows of each table to a csv.

```
$server =  # sql instance name here
$database = # database name here
$outputfolder = # can use values of $server and $database if needed

# if $output doesn't exist: new-item -ItemType Directory $outputfolder

# get list of tables in the database
$tables = (invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database  -Query "select top 10 '[' + object_schema_name(object_id) + '].[' + name + ']' as [Table] from sys.tables order by object_schema_name(object_id), name;").Table


# loop through the tables, exporting each to an individual csv file
foreach ($table in $tables) {

# Remove [] and . characters from table name for the filename
$filename = $table.Replace('[', '').Replace(']', '').Replace('.', '_')

invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database  -Query "select top 5 * from $table;" | export-csv "$outputfolder\$filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation

}


#todo: combine csv files in $outputfolder into a single Excel file.
```

If sticking with powershell you might be able to do something with [Export-Excel](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/) but I haven't tried it myself yet.